# SQL Update statement truncated incorrect double value error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update my table column values into a string. My query goes like this

```
UPDATE   tbl_testing

SET result= 'Hey'

WHERE (SELECT (colOne) + '-' + (colTwo) + '-' + (colThree)) = 'r-r-r'
```

which the columns 'colOne, colTwo and colThree' already contains 'r' but slqyog shows **"Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'r-r-r'"**
  and all of the other result column data became = 'Hey'. What should I do?

Comment: + is not a mysql concat function use concat verb.

Comment: Worked! Thanks @P.Salmon

Comment: `+` is the addition operator. It adds numbers. If its operands are not numbers then MySQL tries to convert them to numbers (of type `DOUBLE`). If you want to concatenate strings, use the [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function.

Comment: Maybe it works but you are doing that in bad way. By doing that you use no indexes and also you are giving more computation tasks to database server. Better way is to add in where statement: `WHERE colOne = 'r' AND colTwo = 'r'` - that will work faster without additional computation need.

Comment: @dey you are right. Develop your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decide it is either `MySQL` or `MSSQL`.

In `MySQL` the string concatenation is not + sign, but simply you enumerate the columns separated by comma and the statement is `SELECT CONCAT("Field1", "Field2" etc) AS ConcatenatedString);` - `CONCAT()` function.

Try reevaluate your `DB` engine and adapt the query.

In `MSSQL` the string concatenation is indeed + sign. Your query works ok in `MSSQL` and updates the `result` column with the value you have set.

**DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_testing](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [result] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [colOne] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [colTwo] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [colThree] [nvarchar](4000) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INTO tbl_testing (id, colOne, colTwo, colThree)
VALUES (1, 'r', 'r', 'r')
```

**Update statement**

```
UPDATE tbl_testing
SET result='Hey. I am a concatenated string'
WHERE (SELECT (colOne)+'-'+(colTwo)+'-'+(colThree))='r-r-r'
```

**Output**

```
id  result                             colOne  colTwo colThree
1   Hey. I am a concatenated string     r         r     r
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing comment to answer:

You should avoid doing that statements in that way. By doing that, database use no indexes and also you are giving more computation tasks to database server (server needs to concatenate all values and after concatenations will compare with given string).

Better way is to replace yours where statement with something like:

```
`WHERE colOne = 'r' AND colTwo = 'r' AND ...`
```

that will work faster without additional computation need (to concatenate strings).

This solution works much much faster, and looks much much better.